# d3 Bubble Chart positioning and text in side bubbles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

I took [this](http://vallandingham.me/gates_bubbles/) example and modified as per my requirement and successfully done, I have **two problems** and need help

**1. The bubbles in google chrome and Edge was not showing properly however in Internet explorer it is showing properly as showing in below image.**

Below picture shows how it is rendered in Internet Explorer
[image: In Internet Explorer]

but it is not rendering in Chrome and Edge properly
[image]

with below style it is showing properly in Internet Explorer

```
.svg-containervis {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**2. I want to show some text on bubbles for example "ABC".**

for text I am following [This](https://bl.ocks.org/ctufts/f38ef0187f98c537d791d24fda4a6ef9) example, I want append "g" and then append "text" tags in below code but I need help to acheive this

```
BubbleChart.prototype.create_vis = function() {
  var that;
  this.vis = d3.select("#vis").append("svg").attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet").attr("viewBox", this.viewBox).classed("svg-content", true).attr("id", "svg_vis");
  this.circles = this.vis.selectAll("circle").data(this.nodes, function(d) {
    return d.id;
  });

  that = this;

  //I want to append "g" and then circle and text below

  this.circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 0).attr("fill", (function(_this) {
     return function(d) {
        return _this.fill_color(d.group);
     };
  })(this))
   .attr("stroke-width", 2)
   .attr("stroke", (function(_this) {
       return function(d) {
      return d3.rgb(_this.fill_color(d.group)).darker();
     };
  })(this))
     .attr("id", function(d) {
       return "bubble_" + d.id;
  })
  .on("click", function(d, i) {
      return that.show_Project_details(d, i, this);
   })
  .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      return that.show_details(d, i, this);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
      return that.hide_details(d, i, this);
  });


  return this.circles.transition().duration(2000).attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.radius;
 });
};
```

I created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AliAdnan/5murzq8L/34/) to view and help.

Thanks

**EDIT as Per  Sujeet Sinha Suggestion**

I changed the text to "A" in order to see the placement of text, please see text are not appearing inside bubbles, I hope we are very near to solve this problem, please help me on this, see the new image I change the below code

```
node.append("text")
.attr("dy", ".3em")
.style("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x;})
.attr("y", function(d) { return d.y;})
.text(function(d) { return "A" });
```

[image]

Comment: what does it look like when you remove 'padding-bottom: 30%;' from your styling ?

Comment: removing 'padding-bottom: 30%;' make all bubbles disappear

Answer (score 2):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yv1pn4uq/).

Basically, you want to apply the following change:

```
.svg-content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
  margin-top: 5%; //this is the change
  overflow: visible; //this is the change
}
```

EDIT:
I've updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kts9nyL/) to display the text as well now. You need to set the styling and animation as per your requirement. To see the changes made, carefully check the `create_vis()` at line 98. Also, you should play with the text co-ordinates at line 138 and 139.

Comment: Hi Sujeet, Its showing correctly, can you please help me to update requirement #2 Text showing part so I accept the answer

Comment: Hi Sujeet, can you please update the fiddle to just some text on bubbles as you suggested

Comment: Hi Sujeet, please check the edit, the text not showing inside the bubble, I updated the question with image

Comment: @AliAdnan, the reason you are not getting the text inside the bubble is because of line number 87 and 88. Everytime you call the value for x and y, a new random value is generated. What you need to do is read the CSV and prepare a dataset and then each function call should be resolved from the prepared dataset and not invoke the `random()` each time.

Comment: please check the function create_nodes() is only calling by line number 66, can explain how it is calling again ?

Comment: @AliAdnan, the function `create_nodes()` might be called once, but please check line 71 and 72. You are effectively returning a function instance, so anytime you loop over the data, the values are recreated. Let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: No Sujeet, I checked you suggested lines but not able to reproduce as you said it is calling loop over the data.